# Segmentation Fault when I put code outside of int main(){}

Tags: c++, for-loop, segmentation-fault, fltk

the first block of code works, but the second block of code doesn't and I have no idea why. I'm getting a segmentation fault with the second block of code.

```
#include "Graph.h"
#include "Simple_window.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities_3.h"

using namespace Graph_lib;

Point t1(100,100);
Simple_window win(t1,700,700,"Calendar");

int main(){
    Vector_ref<Text> weekdays;
    vector<string> weekday = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    for (int a = 0; a < weekday.size(); ++a){
        weekdays.push_back(new Text(Point(a*100+28,90), weekday[a]));
        weekdays[weekdays.size()-1].set_font_size(10);
        win.attach(weekdays[weekdays.size()-1]);
    }
}
```

The following code gives me a segmentation fault.

```
#include "Graph.h"
#include "Simple_window.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities_3.h"

using namespace Graph_lib;

Point t1(100,100);
Simple_window win(t1,700,700,"Calendar");

void draw_weekdays(){
    Vector_ref<Text> weekdays;
    vector<string> weekday = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    for (int a = 0; a < weekday.size(); ++a){
        weekdays.push_back(new Text(Point(a*100 + 28, 90), weekday[a]));
        weekdays[weekdays.size()-1].set_font_size(10);
        win.attach(weekdays[weekdays.size()-1]);
    }
}

int main(){
    draw_weekdays();
}
```

I've narrowed down the issue to the line "win.attach(weekdays[weekdays.size()-1]);", but other than that I'm stumped.

Comment: First make sure your compiler's warnings are turned all the way up (and it's not complaining).  Second, if you're on Linux, use valgrind to narrow down the first memory access error in your program.

Comment: In case you need it, compile your program using -wall and -g

something like this:

g++ myprogram.cpp -wall -g

Comment: -wall isn't recognized by my g++ for some reason.

Comment: @David -Wall, my bad.

Comment: Holy, tons of stuff just came out. Thanks! Time to dissect this.